# Show this does not exist: lim $x^2y^5/(y^2 - x^2)$ as $(x,y) \to(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

i was trying to show it with polar coordinates but it showed that the limit exist however wolfram alpha stated that the limit does not exist so im confused does not polar coordinates proof is enough

Comment: i am sorry for the way i stated the question this is my first time posting here and i wanted help what i did is i substituted x and y with their polar coordinates representatives and got limit = 0 but then i check on wolfram it said limit does not exist

Comment: The ray $(x(t),y(t)) := (t,t)$ is particularly problematic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Alternate approach: consider the subset $~x = ky,~$ for $~k~$ fixed.  Then, prove that the limit varies for different values of $~k.$

Comment: please add your attempt using polar coordinates. Wolfram Alpha is not reliable for 2 variable limits

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to find two curves which approach the origin in different ways. Let's call your function $f$.The first one can be the $x$ axis, it's clear that the limit for $x \to 0$ of $f(x,0)$ is $0$, since $f(x,0)=0 $ for every $x \neq 0$. Then, pass to polar coordinates and your function can be rewritten as $\rho ^5 /(\sin(\theta)^2 - \cos (\theta)^2)$. The last thing to do (try to do this yourself) is to find a curve, or a sequence of points $(\rho_n , \theta_n)$ if you like, such that your function has another limit than $0$ (or none at all). Notice that since you want the denominator to go to $0$ as fast as (or faster) than $\rho^5$, so you're going to have to be near $\pi/4$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

To investigate the limit of the function as $(x, y)$ approaches $(0, 0)$, we can use polar coordinates to rewrite the expression. Let $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$. Then, the expression becomes:

$$
\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{r^2\cos^2(\theta)r^5\sin^5(\theta)}{r^2\sin^2(\theta) - r^2\cos^2(\theta)}
$$

Simplify the expression:

$$
\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{r^7\cos^2(\theta)\sin^5(\theta)}{r^2(\sin^2(\theta) - \cos^2(\theta))}
$$

Now, as $r$ approaches 0, the expression approaches 0. However, the behavior depends on the angle $\theta$. If $\theta = \pi/4$ (45 degrees), the expression approaches $\infty$ because $\sin(45^\circ) = \cos(45^\circ) = 1/\sqrt(2)$, which makes the denominator close to zero. Therefore, the limit does not exist because it depends on the direction in which $(x, y)$ approaches $(0, 0)$.